# Lower bounds for ${{2n} \choose {n}}$

Tags: inequality, factorial, gamma-function, upper-lower-bounds

What are common lower bounds for ${{2n} \choose {n}}$?

---

Edit:  I made a mistake in my original question.

It doesn't change my question but there is no reason for me to include the mistake.

Comment: You could try stirling's approximation on $\frac{(2n)!}{n!^2}$

Comment: Stirling's gives roughly $4^n$  I do not recall the details, but easy enough to do again:

Comment: $2n/n=2$, not $n$.

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1046460/144766) is a tight lower bound for Catalan numbers, which are $\frac{1}{n+1} {2n \choose n}$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the bounds from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/932509), we have
$$
\frac{4^n}{\sqrt{\pi\left(n+\frac13\right)}}\le\binom{2n}{n}\le\frac{4^n}{\sqrt{\pi\left(n+\frac14\right)}}
$$

Comment: good; from Stirling's, the squared denominator keeps an extra $\sqrt n$ compared with the denominator. I wasn't sure yet

Comment: @robjohn is this  a better estimator than Stirling's?

Comment: @gimusi: you can easily notice that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}>\frac{2\sqrt{\pi}}{e^2}$, hence robjohn's bound is sharper than yours. Also because the constant in robjohn's answer is optimal.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio oh yes of course! Indeed it is a very narrow bound. I will take a look to the derivation. Thanks

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio In wich sense is the constant optimal? Is 1/3 the smallest posible real number, such that the inequality holds for all $n$?

Comment: @user: I meant that the constant $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}$ is optimal, since $$ \lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{\sqrt{n}}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}.$$ Notice that $\sqrt{\pi}=\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$, and indeed the identity above follows from Legendre's duplication formula for the $\Gamma$ function.

Comment: @user: note that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left[\,\raise{4pt}{\frac{16^n}{\pi\binom{2n}{n}^2}}-n\,\right]=\frac14$, so the $\frac14$ in the upper bound is optimal. The $\frac13$ in the lower bound can be replaced by $\frac1\pi$ and the inequality will still be valid for $n\ge0$.

Comment: @robjohn Indeed. And $1/\pi$ looks even better than $1/3$.

Answer (score 4):

Using [Stirling's bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation)

$$\sqrt{2\pi}\ n^{n+\frac12}e^{-n} \le n! \le e\ n^{n+\frac12}e^{-n}$$

we obtain

$$\binom{2n}{n}=\frac{(2n)!}{n!^2}\ge\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}\ (2n)^{2n+\frac12}e^{-2n}}{e^2\ n^{2n+1}e^{-2n}}=\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}\ 2^{2n}2^{\frac12}n^{2n+\frac12}}{e^2\ n^{2n+1}}=\frac{2\sqrt{\pi}}{e^2}\frac{4^n}{\sqrt n}$$

Answer (score 1):

Erdös had a really nice lower bound, which he used in his proof of Bertrand's Postulate: $4^n/2n \leqslant {{2n}\choose{n}}$. This follows because
\begin{align*}
(1+1)^{2n}=\sum_{k=0}^{2n} {{2n}\choose{k}}  < 1+2n{{2n}\choose{n}}
\end{align*}
and then $4^n \leqslant 2n{{2n}\choose{n}}$. In fact the bound can be strengthened without too much difficulty to give $4^n/n \leqslant {{2n}\choose{n}}$.

**Edit**: The stronger bound only holds for $n \geqslant 4$.